# rope length and probability

Tags: probability

A point is randomly selected on a line segment of length L. Find the probability that the longer segment is at least twice as long as the shorter segment.

I was thinking that to calculate this I would need to add P(spot in upper 1/3 of rope was selected) + P(spot in lower 1/3 of rope was selected). I think this is a continuous distribution function and that I should be able to integrate 0 to (L/3) + integral (2L/3) to 1. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: The approach as described is fine. What exactly is the difficulty you encountered? BTW, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly typeset any math related expressions.

Comment: Honestly the difficulty is that I'm not a very confident mathematician and want my mistakes caught if I make any.